# Lua Socket: How to send asynchronous http.request?

Tags: lua, luasocket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lua socket asynchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795419/lua-socket-asynchronous-calls)

I think my question is pretty clear. So, how?

Comment: I can't seem to find the answer, post link please?

Comment: Problem is: Those answers answers a different question: Namely how to send raw socket data asynchrounously. Now how to perform an asynch http request with the luasocket http api

Answer (score 6):

Discussed in Programming in Lua ([non-preemptive multithreading](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html)) and on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795419/lua-socket-asynchronous-calls) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333108/how-do-i-deal-with-lua-libraries-that-dont-coroutine-yield/13352683#13352683).

Comment: Yes, that will work, but then you need to roll your own FTP hTTP etc on top of the bare sockets. The LTN stuff does not provide for asynchronous operation; It is simply a fancy callback mechanism during synchronous operation of the protocol engine.

Comment: Answering myself after inspecting ltn12.lua: http.request can probably be wrapped in a coroutine with handling of IO based on lua-ev callbacks and a custom ltn12 sink (key givaway: It can probably be avoided to yield across C barriers). Maybe something for a rainy day. Any outcome shall be posted on this channel ..

Comment: You don't need to roll your own; [copas](https://github.com/keplerproject/copas) provides async http handling (check examples in the `tests/` folder).

Comment: thanks for the pointer